# clear text input on click with php variables

Tags: javascript, php, input, onclick

I want to use the javascript function to clear a text input on click!

but when I use it inside of php I get this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '';" onfocus="this.select()" on' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in

here is the code i'm using:

```
<?php
echo'<input type = "text" name = "mod_n_part" id = "mod_n_part" class="modifica-regole-n_part" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'.$n_part.':this.value;" value = '.$n_part.' />';
?>
```

the php varaible is $n_part as you can see

Answer (score 3):

Change this from:

```
onclick="this.value='';"
```

to:

```
onclick="this.value=\'\';"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just escape the two single quotes with two backslashes as shown.

Like this

```
nclick="this.value=\'\';"
                   ^ ^  ------ Like that.
```

### The proper code

```
echo '<input type = "text" name = "mod_n_part" id = "mod_n_part" class="modifica-regole-n_part" onclick="this.value=\'\';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'.$n_part.':this.value;" value = '.$n_part.' />';
```